# Android database - recreate after update

Tags: android, database

I programmed an app which creates a database when its first started. If I published it to the Google App Store, and provided an update to the app which also included a change in the database schema, the app would probably crash, since it might want to write into a table that doesn't exist in the old database schema.

How can I implement a "check" whether the app has been updated and needs a recreation of the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using the `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods.

You will be adding a

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

variable. Then, you will be incrementing this variable on every upgrade. You will have to write the code necessary for db upgrade in the `onUpgrade` method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html